# Differences between constructors of Job class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

One constructor has no parameters, and the other takes a Configuration object as argument. What is the difference between the two? If no Configuration object is passed, what are the default configuration values?

Answer (score 1):

Where no Configuration is passed, a new Configuration is created, with the default values loaded (in this case the first instance of the *-site.xml files found on the classpath).